# Compile LLVM from source on linux

Tags: makefile, llvm

I've downloaded LLVM [source code](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.9) and I'm trying to compile it.

I've done the basic:

```
./configure --prefix=/some/path/
make
make install
```

But I've another project that depends on it and it seems to be looking for a shared library named: `libLLVM-2.9.so`, which is not built.

When I get llvm through synaptic (I'm using Ubuntu), it does install such library on `/usr/lib` (and llvm root also is installed on /usr/liv/llvm/). My question is: what should I configure so that the code compiled from source generates the `libLLVM-2.9.so`?

PS: Actually I guess this problem is more general, I'm citing llvm as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `--enable-shared` as a configure option?

You can run `./configure --help` to see a list of options `configure` accepts.

Answer (score 2):

Try to download 2.9 release and pass --enable-shared to configure

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build LLVM 3.2 using the following guides

http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/12/building-llvm-32-from-source.html

http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/llvm_build.html